# Find the area enclosed by the curve of equation $y^2=x^4-x^7$

Tags: calculus

I am asked to find the area enclosed by the curve of equation $$y^2=x^4-x^7$$ in the first quadrant.

I recognise that this is when $x\geq0$ and $y\geq0$.

My thoughts so far are as follows:

$$y=\sqrt{x^4-x^7}=\sqrt{x^4(1-x^3)}=x^2\sqrt{1-x^3}$$
I can then see that I need to evaluate $$\int x^2\sqrt{1-x^3}\,dx$$ which I have done and found to be $$\frac{-2}{9}(1-x^3)^\frac{3}{2}+C$$

I'm not sure what the limits I'm supposed to be using though. The solution says $0$ and $1$ but I don't understand why. Could someone explain this?

Comment: Why are you evaluating $\int y$? That is, how are you connecting the area enclosed by a curve $y = y(x)$ to the integral of $y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already identified that this is in the first quadrant, so the lower limit is $\geq 0$.

Does the function cross the $y$ axis (from within the first quadrant)?  If it does, then the lower limit is zero.

Where does the function cross the $x$ axis?  Substitute $y=0$ and that's your upper limit.  $1^4 - 1^7 = ...$

Answer (score 3):

First of all:  $ \ y^2=x^4(1-x^3) \Longleftrightarrow y=\pm x^2 \sqrt{1-x^3}$.

Thus this curve has two branches, symmetrical with respect to $x$ axis.

We are interested in the branch that is situated in the first quadrant, i.e., with cartesian equation:

$$y=x^2 \sqrt{1-x^3} $$

The sign of the expression inside the radical $1-x^3$ has to be positive, thus one must have $x^3 \leq 1$, therefore $x \leq 1$. Thus $0\leq x \leq 1$ (Have a look at the picture below).

I find the same primitive function as you.

The value of the area is thus $2/9$.

[image]